# Limit child widget move range in parent widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

[image]

I am doing a drag and drop widget function. I copied a piece of code on the Internet and rewritten three classes mousePressEvent, mouseReleaseEvent, and mouseMoveEvent.

When the child widget moves to the parent widget's border, it will overwrite the parent widget's border. I don't want it to be like this. I want to keep the parent widget's border. Is there any way to make the child widget only in the content area of the parent widget Move

I tried several ways, but all failed

First: Set the setContentsMargins property of the parent control layout

Second: Set the padding of the parent control

Third: Set the margin of the child control

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QDataStream, QIODevice, QByteArray, QPoint, QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QStyleOption, QPainter, QStyle, QDrag, QListWidgetItem, QIcon, \
    QFontMetricsF, QColor


class Label(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Label, self).__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            *{             border-width: 1px;
             border-style: solid;
             border-color: #cdcdcd;
             background-color:blue
             }
        """)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(Label, self).paintEvent(event)
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
            self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()

        super(Label, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            # adjust offset from clicked point to origin of widget
            currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
            newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)
            self.move(newPos)

            self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos

        super(Label, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
            moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos
            if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
                event.ignore()
                return

        super(Label, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        box = QHBoxLayout()
        box.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.setLayout(box)
        box.addWidget(Label())
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            *{             border-width: 10px;
             border-style: solid;
             border-color: red;}
        """)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(Widget, self).paintEvent(event)
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        h = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        h.addWidget(Widget())
        self.setLayout(h)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 900, 000)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could put an image (or sketch) of what you want to get.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you be more specific, thank you!

Comment: @eyllanescMy previous question was not expressed clearly, I have updated my problem description now, please trouble you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent QWidget is always drawn underneath the child so you see that effect. The solution is to create another child that is on top of the blue child that contains the red border, that occupies the same size as the parent (this is achieved with a layout) and that does not block mouse events (since by default a superior widget lock the mouse to the lower widgets but this can be disabled with the Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents flag).

```py
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        container.setStyleSheet(
            """
            *{             border-width: 10px;
             border-style: solid;
             border-color: red;}
        """
        )

        box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        box.addWidget(container)

        label = Label()
        label.setParent(self)

        container.raise_()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much from afar, you solved my big problem